# Micro-services architecture - common data models

Tags: database-design, architecture, microservices

I'm expriencing with Microservices architecture and i'd like to create a simple project that collect and persist data from some dynamic source (Web crawler/stock prices/etc'), aggregates/calculate something based on that data, and displays it in a web page.

I am trying to separate this into multiple projects/services, for example :
1. Docker running code to collect and persiste the data.
2. REST Server for API's to display/aggregate queries based on the data we collected .
3. UI Framework that displays data given by the REST API's

The problem i'd like to discuss is the shared model between 1 and 2.
Let's say the code base for this entire thing is seperated into three projects/JARs - TestAPP, TestAPI, and TestUI.  TestAPP is persisting data that TestAPI will use, should TestAPP be a dependency of TestAPI ? Should they have some sort of common dependency? Should something like this be handled by three different projects? three JARs under the same project?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll want to have many different TestAPP, with different technologies, number of instances, lifecycles, ...
And only one TestAPI.

I would expose the TestAPP with an API (REST ? GraphQL ?) that will be used by TestAPI. This contract is thus a kind of dependancy, but very light and only based on the interface.

Next TestAPP you create will only have to implement this contract.

Comment: If you meant integration through the database, the same principle applies : make a contract on the databases, for example with views.